# If 'Amlonde' were a word in Sindarin or Quenya, what would it mean?

Tags: tolkien-elvish

I learned that in the real world Amlonde is a given name of South African origin (I cannot be more precise on linguistic background or meaning). But the word looks suspiciously like a word from Tolkien's Elvish languages. I looked it up in Helmut Pesch's dictionary, but it is not attested there.

So my question is: Can this word be analysed in Sindarin and/or Quenya, and what would it mean than?

EDIT: Some clarifications on possible answers: I am not looking for arbitrary suggestions of a meaning. Any analysis shall be based on published material on Sindarin and Quenya, including diachronic development and lesser known dialects. An answer that the word is in fact impossible in Quenya or Sindarin with some argument why this is the case is also a legitimate answer.

Comment: I don't think "ml" is a legal sequence in Quenya.

Comment: Interesting. Skimming through the dictionary suggests that this is indeed the case: -lm- occurs frequently, but -ml- is suspiciously absent. *lomelinde* has a vowel kept between the *m* and the *l*.—P.S. I consider an answer of the type: "It is not a legal word in Quenya or SIndarin" with some argumentation why it is so an acceptable answer to this question.

Comment: Many languages have character/phoneme combinations that are not legal, but which occur nevertheless at segment boundaries (like English doesn't really use "nm" as a legal sequence, but it still occurs in "unmittigated" etc.) Could this be similar, where "Am" is a prefix and "londe" a stem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a neat analysis in Quenya according to a [Tolkien Dictionary Site](https://www.elfdict.com/):

> [*am-*](https://www.elfdict.com/w/am): is a prefix that means "up"
>
> [*londë*](https://www.elfdict.com/w/londe): means "(landlocked) haven"

So you can imagine it describing a place that once was a harbour, but through geographical changes has become landlocked, and is possibly on a hill or mountain. Or it could be a refuge, a safe place in the mountains.

Comment: Is there a landlocked *londe* in canon?  Two *londi* that spring to mind are *Alqualonde* ‘Swan-haven’, where the Noldor seized the Telerin ships, and *Mithlond* ‘Grey-haven’, where Frodo embarked. There's also *Lond Daer*, the ‘great port’ of the Second Age, at the mouth of the Greyflood.